# QGIS clip grid frame to shape?

Tags: qgis, clip, print-composer, grids-graticules

I am working in QGIS and would like the grid frame to align with the edges of my conic projection region. Is there a way to do this? In arc it is very straightforward but I have yet to find a method within print composer. Does anyone know of a plugin capable of clipping frames? The region is between lat 52 and lat 60.5, and between lon --115 and lon -126. The projection is canada equal area albers conic (epsg:102001). See image below for reference:

[image]

Comment: Could you send the data please?

Comment: i don't know how to send data from here, but the region is between lat 52 and lat 60.5, and between lon --115 and lon -126. The projection is canada equal area albers conic (epsg:102001)